# Java 8 parallelStream forEach iteration

Tags: foreach, java-8

Iterating the list using parallelStream in forEach is giving me the less records in map. I have **3000** items in list, when I iterate using parallelStream and put into the HashMap giving me **2963** records. See the below code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {        
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();      
    for(int i=0;i<3000;i++) {
    list.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }       
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();     
    list.parallelStream().forEach(s -> {
        map.put(s, s);
    });         
    System.out.println("size-->"+map.size());       
}
```

Can anyone explain how this working.

Note: the above code works fine if I use list.forEach without parallelStream.

```
list.forEach(s -> {
        map.put(s, s);
    });
```

Comment: use `list.parallelStream().collect(toMap(s -> s, s -> s))`.

Comment: @Aomine thx... do not even know why I answered this... my bad

Comment: Thanks all..but what is toMap in list.parallelStream().collect(toMap(s -> s, s -> s))

Comment: @mohammedsameen see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function- and http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors